# What is the zsh equivalent of bash's "command" command?

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, zsh

I've overwritten my `cd` command with `pushd` so I don't have to remember to use `pushd` and can easily get back to where I've been.  Now I want to use the *actual* `cd` command.

In bash, I would use `command cd "$@"`, but `command cd` doesn't work in zsh.  Does zsh have an equivalent?  `command`--whatever it is in zsh--doesn't have a man entry.

Comment: See also the `auto_pushd` option if you want `cd` to push directories to the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd` is a shell *builtin* command, so just use `builtin cd "$@"` to get the original behavior. There is also `command ...` but which applies only to *external* commands in *zsh*. Both are explained in `man zshbuiltins` or have a look into the *PRECOMMAND MODIFIERS* section in `man zshmisc`.